# JQuery Templates - Use string as data

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-templates

I am using jQuery templates to create a message dialog. The only data that needs passed is a message which is a string. The problem I face and have not seen documented is how I should reference the message data in my template when it is not wrapped in an object:

```
$.tmpl('messageAlertTmpl', message).appendTo(dialog);
```

With this I can't reference the data as `${message}` because message is the outer object, so the property is undefined.

All examples I have seen just use properties of an object to reference the data within the template, which would  cause me to have to do something like this:

```
$.tmpl('messageAlertTmpl', { message: message }).appendTo(dialog);
```

I was thinking that `$value` may work like it does with `{{each}}` however this does not seem to be the case.

Is this possible?

Comment: why don't you want to do `{message: message}`?

Comment: @jesse reiss - Its unnecessary

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I *think* you can use `$data` but I'm working on a jsfiddle to be sure :-)

*edit* [yes that works](http://jsfiddle.net/VsAUu/) though it's a little ugly — inside the template string, `${$data}` will expand to the value of the whole "data" object. Thus:

```
$.tmpl("Hello ${$data}", "world").appendTo("#x");
```

will append "Hello world" to element "x".

Answer (score 1):

`$data` is a reference to the current data object (which is the message in your case). That should work.